# Pig Translator with method

Tags: java, methods

```
import java.util.Scanner;    

public class Mission04Blossom {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String inputWord = "";
        String translatedWord = "";

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Pig Latin Translator *Oink* ");

        System.out.println("Please enter a word to be translated: ");
        inputWord = in.nextLine();

        translatedWord = pigTranslator(inputWord);

        System.out.println(translatedWord);
    }

    public static String pigTranslator(String userWord) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        char wordFirstLetter = userWord.charAt(0);

        String newFirstLetter = String.valueOf(wordFirstLetter);

            if (newFirstLetter.equalsIgnoreCase("a") || newFirstLetter.equalsIgnoreCase("e") || newFirstLetter.equalsIgnoreCase("i") || newFirstLetter.equalsIgnoreCase("o") || newFirstLetter.equalsIgnoreCase("u")) {
                userWord = userWord + "way";
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < userWord.length(); i++) {
                    if (userWord.charAt(i) == 'a' || userWord.charAt(i) == 'e' || userWord.charAt(i) == 'i' || userWord.charAt(i) == 'o' || userWord.charAt(i) == 'u') {
                        userWord = userWord.substring(i, userWord.length()) + userWord.substring(0, i) + "ay";

                    }
                }
            }    
        return userWord;    
    }
}
```

Alright, maybe someone can help me. I'm having no luck. I know this is probably super inefficient, but I'm still learning. This is a Pig Latin translator. I want to make it so the user will have to enter another word after the first one has been translated. I've tried so many combinations and such, but no avail. I KNOW this is just a simple logic error and once someone points it out to me, it will make so much sense and I'll feel stupid for not seeing it.

Essentially I want something like
Please enter another word or press Q to quit.
if they press q it says thanks for playing, otherwise, it returns and prints

Comment: Please explain what the problem is, as precisely as possible.

Comment: I'm trying to get the program to ask the user for another word after the previously translated word until they press Q to quit. If that makes sense.

Comment: In what *specific* ways is your program not doing what you want?

Comment: So translated word works fine I have it so the program runs once. However If I put something like print out "Please enter another word or press Q to quit" it allows me to input a word, but nothing happens. Like I tried using a do-while loop around the if-else in the method where it checks for if the first letter is a vowel, but it doesn't loop. It just goes to another entry and won't print out the translated word. I hope that's specific enough. There's no error, I just can't seem to get the program to loop so it asks the user for another word.

Comment: Why does `pigTranslator` need a `Scanner`?

Comment: Because one of the edits I made was to have the user enter a word after it was translated and I just forgot to remove it.

Comment: Please post the code with the loop you tried.